SwiftUI NavigationSplitView title appearing as inline instead of large title unless scrolled
I discovered a really weird issue with the title on the sidebar on iPads. I've set the navigationBarTitleDisplayMode to .large, but on first load (right after I run the app on the simulator), the title is shown as inline but if I pull the list downwards (scrolling up), the title becomes large. It's as if the list is scrolled up on first load. But the list is fully visible so it doesn't really appear like it was scrolled. I hope my explanation makes sense.
Here's a sample code:
NavigationSplitView {
        VStack {
            List(folders, id: \.self, selection: $selectedFolder) { folder in
                NavigationLink(folder.title, value: folder)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button {
                //Create new list
                newListModalShown = true
            } label: {
                Text("New List")
            }
        }
    } detail: {
        if let selectedFolder {
            ItemsListView(folder: selectedFolder)
        } else {
            Text("Select a list")
                .navigationTitle("")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }

Here are some screenshots of the UI:

On app first run (actual result):



When scrolling list downwards / expected result on first run):


I've done a few troubleshooting steps to check what's causing the problem, unfortunately, I've not figured it out:

I replaced the code inside the 'List' with just Text, just to see if the title appeared large, no go.
Tried scrollview with a few lines of text, that seemed to work. But I'd rather stick to List
– Moved the modifer .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode around to see if that made a difference, it didn't

I am hoping it's just not me who experienced this problem. I'd be happy to report this as a bug if indeed it is. Just wanted to know if anybody else had found a work around.
Thanks!
Update:
Went with @Benzy Neez's solution #1. Both suggested workarounds worked, but solution #1 aligned more with what I wanted to implement.

I agree that it looks like a bug.
Here are some workarounds:
1. Launch the view with the sidebar visible
The title is large if the sidebar is visible when the view is first shown:
@State private var visibility = NavigationSplitViewVisibility.doubleColumn

NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $visibility) {
    // ...
}

2. Show the title as a section header instead
If the List is wrapped with a Section, the title can be shown as the section header:
Section {
    List(folders, id: \.self, selection: $selectedFolder) { folder in
        NavigationLink(folder.title, value: folder)
    }
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .navigationTitle("")
} header: {
    Text("Test Title")
        .padding(.leading, 20)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
}


Ah these look like they're excellent workarounds. Either of these two will do, at least for now. I'll give these a try, if these solutions work, I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thanks!!

I tried both solutions, they both worked! But I have decided to go with solution #1 as solution #2 takes out that feature where the title reduces to an inline size when scrolling upwards. Thanks again for the suggested workarounds!

This issue appears to have been fixed in iOS 18 SDK in Xcode 16.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
